# How to install Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

So I am trying to install Eclipse on a Windows computer, but I am stuck. I am following the step to step guide from the website [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/install-eclipse-java.html). My problem is step 4. I only get a zip-file after clicking on “Download” button. When I try to click on the zip-file, it only shows me several folders. I don't get the box with the run button. Does someone have some tips?

Comment: The Eclipse IDE packages for Windows are available as ZIP files and via the _Eclipse Installer_. The guide refers to the Eclipse Installer. See Rownum Highart answer below.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

Click on the link with the .exe file, not any other link. If you have difficulty, use this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2021-12/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe), then continue with the guide...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I used the link you gave me and then it worked! :)